# Spring Integration Email

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

What is the basic code to poll on a generic email account with inner folders for emails with attachments and get the data for further processing in spring integration?

Comment: See [the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#mail). You need to make your question more specific.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, Can you please advice if IMAP and POP3 can only be used for inbound adapters? Can we use port 25 for a relay server to receive mails and configure for a flow?

Comment: Port 25 is for SMTP (outbound only). Spring Integration doesn't provide an SMTP server.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, Sorry for repeated q's, but to initially get it setup to my org's email account or my gmail account, any conf changes to be done from mail server? or just telnet imap.gmail.com 110 or 993 or 995 is enough?

Comment: GMail doesn't support javamail clients by default - see https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps